# Clarity on Android not responding dialog root cause

Tags: java, android, multithreading, intentservice, android-anr-dialog

I have a customer who is using a proof of concept Android app I created for them and they are reporting an Android not responding dialog that I cannot reproduce on my own devices.

So I got them to get the traces.txt file off the device and it shows my apps process as being in the following state:

```
----- pid 28889 at 2016-05-11 11:34:41 -----
DALVIK THREADS (41):
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Suspended
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x779f8ea8 self=0x42427800
  | sysTid=28889 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x40014bec
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=58623 stm=1934 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe0a5000-0xbe0a7000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:353)
  - locked <0x2ce9a45a> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
  at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:507)
  at android.app.IntentService.onStart(IntentService.java:119)
  at android.app.IntentService.onStartCommand(IntentService.java:130)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3979)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:210)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1802)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=3 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ca00a0 self=0x42427c00
  | sysTid=28896 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x42503f80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x43072000-0x43074000 stackSize=1012KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 0003b5bc  /system/lib/libc.so (recvmsg+8)
  native: #01 pc 002909cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::JdwpAdbState::ReceiveClientFd()+90)
  native: #02 pc 00290abf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::JdwpAdbState::Accept()+106)
  native: #03 pc 00196b37  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::JdwpState::Run()+286)
  native: #04 pc 0019807b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::StartJdwpThread(void*)+10)
  native: #05 pc 00017667  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
  native: #06 pc 00015687  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ca30a0 self=0x4748c000
  | sysTid=28898 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x4744f080
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=71 stm=112 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x4327c000-0x4327e000 stackSize=1036KB

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ca3100 self=0x4748c400
  | sysTid=28899 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x4744f580
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=351 stm=188 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x43384000-0x43386000 stackSize=1036KB

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=8 Sleeping
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ca3160 self=0x4748c800
  | sysTid=28901 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x4744f800
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=2 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x47943000-0x47945000 stackSize=1036KB

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=9 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cba0a0 self=0x4242c800
  | sysTid=28902 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x42503a80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=5703 stm=922 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x48e04000-0x48e06000 stackSize=1012KB

"HeapTrimmerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=10 Sleeping
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ca31c0 self=0x4748cc00
  | sysTid=28903 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x4744fa80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=25 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x53636000-0x53638000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.trimHeap(Native method)
  - sleeping on an unknown object
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:328)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"GCDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=4 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ca3220 self=0x4748d000
  | sysTid=28904 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x4744fd00
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1611 stm=210 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x5373a000-0x5373c000 stackSize=1036KB

"Measurement Worker" prio=5 tid=11 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12dc69a0 self=0x4242ac00
  | sysTid=28906 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x42503300
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x549cc000-0x549ce000 stackSize=1036KB

"Measurement Network" prio=5 tid=12 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12dc6a00 self=0x42428c00
  | sysTid=28907 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x42503580
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x54ad0000-0x54ad2000 stackSize=1036KB

"pool-2-thread-1" prio=5 tid=13 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12de44c0 self=0x4242f000
  | sysTid=28908 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x42506a00
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x54bd4000-0x54bd6000 stackSize=1036KB

"Queue" prio=10 tid=14 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e5bfa0 self=0x42430000
  | sysTid=28909 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x42504980
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x54cd8000-0x54cda000 stackSize=1036KB

"Queue" prio=10 tid=15 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e640a0 self=0x42430400
  | sysTid=28910 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x42506000
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=14 stm=3 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x54ddc000-0x54dde000 stackSize=1036KB

"Queue" prio=10 tid=16 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e64100 self=0x42430800
  | sysTid=28911 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x42506280
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x54ee0000-0x54ee2000 stackSize=1036KB

"Queue" prio=10 tid=17 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e64160 self=0x42430c00
  | sysTid=28912 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x42507400
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x54fe4000-0x54fe6000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x162011b9> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x162011b9> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"Queue" prio=10 tid=18 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e641c0 self=0x42431000
  | sysTid=28913 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x42507680
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x550e8000-0x550ea000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x1f2419fe> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x1f2419fe> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"Answers Events Handler1" prio=5 tid=19 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e64e20 self=0x42431c00
  | sysTid=28916 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x42507b80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=23 stm=10 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x552f0000-0x552f2000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x1abea55f> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x1abea55f> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1048)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:776)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"Crashlytics Exception Handler1" prio=5 tid=20 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ef2520 self=0x42431400
  | sysTid=28917 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x42507e00
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x551ec000-0x551ee000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x00098bac> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x00098bac> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"Thread-4649" prio=5 tid=25 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12f2bcf0 self=0x42774800
  | sysTid=28952 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x427ed380
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x56f98000-0x56f9a000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x1fa71075> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x1fa71075> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
  at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:90)

"Thread-4650" prio=5 tid=26 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12f2bd60 self=0x42774c00
  | sysTid=28953 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x427ed100
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=19 stm=5 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x5709c000-0x5709e000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x10a3d80a> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x10a3d80a> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)

"Thread-4651" prio=5 tid=27 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12f2bdd0 self=0x42775000
  | sysTid=28954 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x427ee280
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x571a0000-0x571a2000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x2352387b> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x2352387b> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)

"Thread-4652" prio=5 tid=28 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12f2be40 self=0x42775400
  | sysTid=28955 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x427ee500
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x572a4000-0x572a6000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x0159b698> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x0159b698> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)

"Thread-4653" prio=5 tid=29 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12f2beb0 self=0x42775800
  | sysTid=28956 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x427edd80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x573a8000-0x573aa000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x3a653ef1> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x3a653ef1> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)


"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=31 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ff2f40 self=0x42779000
  | sysTid=28969 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x427eea00
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x575dd000-0x575df000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x25c1e157> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x25c1e157> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"IntentService[MSBandIS]" prio=5 tid=33 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x13076eb0 self=0x4277d400
  | sysTid=29119 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x427f0300
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=10612 stm=10028 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x56dc4000-0x56dc6000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 0001341c  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 000acb5b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::Wait(art::Thread*)+82)
  native: #02 pc 0028b215  /system/lib/libart.so (art::GoToRunnable(art::Thread*)+756)
  native: #03 pc 0008a579  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*)+8)
  native: #04 pc 00071621  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_database_sqlite_SQLiteConnection_nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId__JJ+124)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:952)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1609)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1479)
  at com.hpes.msbandtest.content.SensorProvider.insert(SensorProvider.java:150)
  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:243)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1260)
  at com.hpes.msbandtest.bandlisteners.MSBandIntentService.onHandleIntent(MSBandIntentService.java:47)
  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

"GAC_Executor[0]" prio=5 tid=34 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x130c2d60 self=0x4760b400
  | sysTid=29130 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x47453680
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x5788c000-0x5788e000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x067fa444> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x067fa444> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"GAC_Executor[1]" prio=5 tid=36 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12edbe80 self=0x4277dc00
  | sysTid=29131 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x427f0800
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x58530000-0x58532000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x38fdd92d> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x38fdd92d> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"Binder_4" prio=5 tid=40 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x132050a0 self=0x4277b000
  | sysTid=29397 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x5636c100
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=5648 stm=899 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x576e3000-0x576e5000 stackSize=1012KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 0003bccc  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  native: #01 pc 00052be1  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  native: #02 pc 0001f5ef  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+138)
  native: #03 pc 0001fadf  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
  native: #04 pc 0001fb41  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
  native: #05 pc 00023cd7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (???)
  native: #06 pc 000106b5  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+112)
  native: #07 pc 00065369  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+72)
  native: #08 pc 00010225  /system/lib/libutils.so (???)
  native: #09 pc 00017667  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
  native: #10 pc 00015687  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)

"IntentService[DetectedActivitiesIS]" prio=5 tid=24 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ddc510 self=0x4242b400
  | sysTid=30481 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x58915980
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=9 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x58387000-0x58389000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 0003b6cc  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
  native: #01 pc 00015923  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+26)
  native: #02 pc 00015931  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+6)
  native: #03 pc 00012733  /system/lib/libutils.so 
----- end 28889 -----
```

I've had to cut a lot of text out of the trace to get within Stackoverflows limits and the trace is rather large my apologies for that and if there is anything missing that could be useful please let me know and I will add it back in.

The main thread is clearly Suspended for some reason. What does Suspended refer to?

I also notice that it seems to reference IntentService in the main thread report, then later on in the trace we can see reference to the two IntentServices my app has - IntentService[MSBandIS] & IntentService[DetectedActivitiesIS] - both of these have "native" beside them, what does this mean? Are they running correctly?

The only reference to code in my app is as follows:

> at
>   com.hpes.msbandtest.content.SensorProvider.insert(SensorProvider.java:150)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:243)
>   at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1260)
>   at
>   com.hpes.msbandtest.bandlisteners.MSBandIntentService.onHandleIntent(MSBandIntentService.java:47)

This is where I insert a very large string into the content provider like this:

```
@Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

        /**
         * Add a new sensor record
         */
        long rowID = db.insert(SENSOR_TABLE_NAME, "", values);

        /**
         * If record is added successfully
         */

        if (rowID > 0)
        {
            Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
            return _uri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to add a record into " + uri);
    }
```

And this is done using an IntentService like so:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        // Gets data from the incoming Intent
        String valuesString = workIntent.getStringExtra("data");

        String test = "";

        try {
            test = CryptoHelper.getInstance(this).encryptString(valuesString);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            return;
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); //Create a content values object
        values.put(SensorProvider.SENSOR_DATA, test); //Add the event data

        getContentResolver().insert(
                SensorProvider.CONTENT_URI, values); //Insert into the Content provider

    }
```

So as you can see I use encryption and the String is going to be VERY long however I am using an IntentService so this shouldn't be blocking the Main Thread, correct?

So I am confused as to how an ANR is appearing? Any ideas? Am I reading the trace right or does it actually point to something else?

ADDING Start service code for roarster:

```
private void insertIntoCP(String valuesString){
    Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(mContext, MSBandIntentService.class);
    mServiceIntent.putExtra("data", valuesString);
    mContext.s.startService(mServiceIntent);
}
```

Comment: are you testing it on the same device of your client? Does its device have a custom rom ?

Comment: No, its not possible for me to replicate the set up the client has, so the trace is my best chance at resolving the issue. No custom ROM either.

Comment: what does the code look like that calls `startService()`? There's a useful summary of Dalvik thread states [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207231/what-are-the-dalvik-thread-states/23207285).

Comment: Added that code to the question at the end, the call is in a standard Java class that itself gets instantiated in a Service.